# What research explains political attitudes of academics?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, politics

According to the [Times of Higher Education](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/democrats-far-outnumber-republicans-social-sciences#survey-answer), there are more liberals* than conservatives in the social sciences. The ratio of Democrats to Republicans in economics is 5:1, in law it is 9:1, in psychology 17:1, in journalism 20:1, and in history a whopping 33:1.

From my experience, this trend extends outside the social sciences, i.e. to the humanities and the natural sciences, although it may be strongest in the former. I don't have data handy to back this up.

Is there any **serious empirical research** into why professionals in academia are more likely to vote democratic than the average of the population? If so, what are the main explanations? (Candidates could be self-selection, socialization, or confounding variables like income and education.)

> **Moderator’s notice:** As per [this meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4177/7734), all answers to this question must provide external references. Please avoid any discussion about politics (rule of thumb: it should not be possible to deduce your political opinion from your writing). Answers and comments not adhering to this will be deleted without warning.

Comment: In order to avoid that this question is closed as opinion-based, I suggest to request specifically answers that are based on existing empirical studies rather than individual conjecture. Otherwise, we will just get a lot of answers advocating a particular world-view in a competitive spirit.

Comment: I'm missing any indication about STEM field political views in the study. My observation in Europe (mostly Germany) is that social sciences and humanities tend to much further left (European meaning of term) than STEM fields. In European political terminology, I mean *left* as opposed to *liberal* or *conservative*.

Comment: @BenSandeen: The study gives rather detailed results which (not surprisingly) have a huge variance between universities. I'm not familiar enough with the academic landscape in the US to judge whether their selection of universities was representative or biased - but with what I know from Europe, their selection of fields probably distorts findings. And they are looking at registered voters (for economics, that's little more than 1/3 of the professors). Voters for one side may be more probable to register (possible bias). The study does not discuss any of these possible sources of bias.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less opinion-based and to incorporate some of the comments. I'm voting to reopen the question, which I consider highly relevant to academia.

Comment: [Meta discussion on this question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4177/7734).

Comment: I would suggest removing or amending the sentence "This would perhaps be called socialist or progressive in Europe." as it is quite misleading. Many of the policies advocated by the nominal "left" in the US would be viewed as already right-leaning in most of Europe (except perhaps the UK). Certainly not "socialist". The closest would be "social democratic", but even that is a stretch. Perhaps "social liberalism". The comparison is so stretched that it is hardly useful.

Comment: I edited it to remove the controversial description of "liberalism" and its relationship to European political views, and instead kept it focused on the American political spectrum.

Comment: I am the OP and while I no longer recognize the question as it's been modified so much none of my original text still exists, I appreciate the effort that has gone into editing it and am happy to leave it be :)

Comment: This has appeared in the review queue with requests to close as "primarily opinion-based". Possibly those votes took place before the edits happened, but I'm voting to leave open because as it currently stands, this question is asking for studies based evidence.

Comment: What is the asterisk supposed to refer to now? There's no note.

Answer (score 14):

I really do not think we are going to get to any causal relationship here. One thing you might want to consider is the link between IQ and politics.

People with higher IQ (generally) tend to be more liberal:
https://theconversation.com/do-smart-people-tend-to-be-more-liberal-yes-but-it-doesnt-mean-all-conservatives-are-stupid-57713

Childhood IQ in Britain, for a 1970s cohort, predicts voting for more liberal parties (Greens and Lib Dems):
https://www.research.ed.ac.uk/portal/files/8896159/childhood_intelligence_predicts_voter.pdf

This answer is only meant as a starting point. You would need to consider all of the evidence from across the world (perhaps the reverse is true, in general, for example. And perhaps other variables come into play).

Comment: But I also said I don't think we are going to get any causal relationship. It's merely a suggestion of an area to investigate. A starting point, as I said.

Comment: Maybe you should be commenting this, rather than answering then

Comment: I can totally deduce your political opinion from your writing!

Comment: @KamilSJaron - no you can't. But the reason you think you can is because the cited research suggests that high-IQ is associated with particular voting choices (in a particular political context, i.e., the UK). Nothing I can do about that, it's what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 12):

One of the biggest predictors of political ideology in the US right now is a personality trait called "openness to experience" which is define roughly as "breadth, depth, originality and complexity of thought, coming up with novel ways to do things."  This is very close to describing exactly what academics do.  A 1 point increase in openness to experience (between -2 and 2) is associated with a 9 point increase in likeliness to vote for Clinton over Trump.  See [this summary](http://evidencebase.usc.edu/the-association-between-personality-traits-and-voting-intentions-in-the-2016-presidential-election/) of the relevant research.

Answer (score 4):

I also do not think we are going to get to any causal relationship here. One other factor that have crossed my mind to explain this link is attitude towards immigration. I am not from USA, but I got this impression that democrats were more for-immigration than republicans.

I found some backups for the impression tn the study "[Race, Religion, and Immigration in 2016](https://www.voterstudygroup.org/publications/2016-elections/race-religion-immigration-2016)" they showed that immigration was one of the strongest factors that motivated voters of 2012 republican candidate in the presidential election to vote again for 2016 republican candidate (Figure 2). In the Figure 3 they also show that immigration is considered as way more serious problem among republican supporters, in comparison to voters of democrats.

Then I wanted to figure what is the proportion of immigrants among academics. It's harder than I expected, but this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/10/education/10presidents.html) from 2011 says that there were 115,000 "international scholars" working at colleges and universities in the United States. If the calculations from [this blogpost](http://www.richardprice.io/post/12855561694/the-number-of-academics-and-graduate-students-in) are correct, there are ~7.5% of immigrants among academics. The frequency of migration in academia is so high that leaves very little space to fight against it.

In conclusion, I think that academics will be always in favor of migration.  Note that this factor does not require an assumption about intelligence of academics.

Comment: Not only are academics more likely to have colleagues who are immigrants, we've typically done a lot more international travel, and often to have worked internationally.

Answer (score 3):

In a study published in [Nature Neuroscience](https://www.nature.com/articles/nn1979), the authors are trying to test whether

> "conservatives show more structured and persistent cognitive styles, whereas liberals are more responsive to informational complexity, ambiguity and novelty."

They find that

> "greater liberalism was associated with stronger conflict-related anterior cingulate activity, suggesting greater neurocognitive sensitivity to cues for altering a habitual response pattern."

(Both quoted from the abstract.)

This suggests that a skill that is highly valued in academia is less prevalent among conservatives. It is unlikely (though not impossible) that identifying as conservative changes cognitive functioning and thus there is even a tentatively causal relationship.

There is also evidence published in [Science](https://www.science.org/doi/full/10.1126/science.1153651) that individual differences in inequity aversion have correlates in the activity of different brain regions. Given the experimental setup (subjects engage in a moral dilemma during the measurement), causality between brain activity and behavior is unclear here.

Both studies are embedded in a large literature (do check out both cited papers and citing papers!) that to my understanding establishes a link between certain cognitive functions and political and moral beliefs. If these cognitive functions are useful in academia, this may explain the political attitudes of academics.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is discussed at length in [article [1]](https://journalofcontroversialideas.org/article/3/1/236), which was coauthored by 29 established scholars from Oxford, MIT, Technion, Brown, Columbia, Vanderbilt, etc., including two Nobel Prize winners. From that 26-page long treatise, I would single out three points.

(a)  In the past, the hiring process of faculty at major American universities was based on merit. An applicant was supposed to provide (along with the CV & publication list) two documents: Research Statement and Teaching Statement.  Over the past years, the situation changed, in that applicants now have to submit also a political document named *DEI Statement* which, on many occasions, outweighs the research and teaching statements. For academic jobs in the Life Sciences at UC Berkeley, for instance, each DEI statement is ranked on three criteria: knowledge of DEI, track record of DEI work, plans to implement DEI initiatives if hired). This is done using a point system (15 points total). If the statement doesn’t accrue enough points, the application is rejected and is not considered again. This is why in recent faculty searches in the life sciences at UC Berkeley, three quarters of the candidates were eliminated solely on the basis on their DEI statements. [[2]](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2021/09/28/an-ad-for-a-biology-professor-in-which-commitment-to-diversity-far-outweighs-commitment-to-teaching-and-research/), [[3]](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2019/12/31/life-science-jobs-at-berkeley-with-hiring-giving-precedence-to-diversity-and-inclusion-statements/), [[4]](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2023/01/24/a-thread-about-universty-dei-statements/).

(b)  DEI statements are often expected to embrace CSJ; statements that express support for the ideals of liberal social justice, such as Dr. Martin Luther King Jr.’s dream of a colourblind society, are rejected. As UC Berkeley’s sample rubric for evaluating diversity statements states, candidates who intend to treat “all students the same regardless of their background” will be given the lowest score. [[5]](https://ofew.berkeley.edu/recruitment/contributions-diversity/rubric-assessing-candidate-contributions-diversity-equity)

(c)  Some universities have begun to incorporate DEI statements in tenure and promotion. This policy is being introduced, for example, by the University of Indiana [[6]](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2021/05/14/iupui-creates-path-promotion-and-tenure-based-dei-work) and the University of Illinois in Urbana-Champaign. [[7]](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2022/04/01/u-illinois-require-diversity-statements-tenure)

For more details on this process and its possible consequences, see the afore-cited [paper [1]](https://journalofcontroversialideas.org/article/3/1/236).

[[1](https://journalofcontroversialideas.org/article/3/1/236)] D. Abbot et al. [In Defense of Merit in Science](https://journalofcontroversialideas.org/article/3/1/236). *Journal of Controversial Ideas* 2023, 3(1), 1-26. doi: 10.35995/jci03010001

[[2](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2021/09/28/an-ad-for-a-biology-professor-in-which-commitment-to-diversity-far-outweighs-commitment-to-teaching-and-research/)] J. Coyne. [When Commitment to Diversity Outweighs Teaching and Research in a Biology Job](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2021/09/28/an-ad-for-a-biology-professor-in-which-commitment-to-diversity-far-outweighs-commitment-to-teaching-and-research/). (2021)

[[3](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2019/12/31/life-science-jobs-at-berkeley-with-hiring-giving-precedence-to-diversity-and-inclusion-statements/)] J. Coyne. [Life Science Jobs at Berkeley Give Precedence to Candidates' Diversity and Inclusion Statements](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2019/12/31/life-science-jobs-at-berkeley-with-hiring-giving-precedence-to-diversity-and-inclusion-statements/) (2019)

[[4](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2023/01/24/a-thread-about-universty-dei-statements/)] J. Coyne. [A Thread about University DEI Statements](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2023/01/24/a-thread-about-universty-dei-statements/) (2023)

[[5](https://ofew.berkeley.edu/recruitment/contributions-diversity/rubric-assessing-candidate-contributions-diversity-equity)]  [Rubric for Assessing Candidate Contributions to Diversity, Equity, Inclusion, and Belonging, UC Berkeley.](https://ofew.berkeley.edu/recruitment/contributions-diversity/rubric-assessing-candidate-contributions-diversity-equity)

[[6](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2021/05/14/iupui-creates-path-promotion-and-tenure-based-dei-work)]  C. Flaherty, [The DEI Pathway to Promotion.](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2021/05/14/iupui-creates-path-promotion-and-tenure-based-dei-work) *Inside Higher Education* (2021),

[[7](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2022/04/01/u-illinois-require-diversity-statements-tenure)] C. Flaherty, [Where DEI Work Is Faculty Work.](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2022/04/01/u-illinois-require-diversity-statements-tenure) *Inside Higher Education* (2022),

Comment: Diversity statements are certainly one of the mechanisms through which the current ideological skew is *preserved*, but this does not really explain how this ideological skew, which predates the current rise of diversity statements, *arose*. (Of course, I don't think that there's any deep mystery in this: it's hardly surprising that in Western societies, where the dominant form of inequality and discrimination is educational in nature and has been for quite a while, highly educated cosmopolitans would be drawn to a worldview which both distracts from and justifies their position of power.)

Comment: @AdamPřenosil The ideological skew certainly predates the modern policies. In the past, however, ideological discrimination in the hiring process in academia generally didn't exist -- or, at least, wasn't official.

Answer (score -4):

David French is the president of the Foundation for Individual Rights in Education, a nonpartisan group that monitors free speech on campus. In a 2005 interview with ABC News [1], French argued that "the universities have been so captured by the left point of view, that you're going to get more political and intellectual diversity at your average suburban mega-church than you are at an elite university." The cause, he believed, was the systematic suppression and censorship of conservatives.

That same year, Rothman, Nevitte and Lichter published a paper [2] using data based on a telephone survey in 1999 of approximately 4000 faculty, administrators, and students. The purpose of this study was to test if professional advancement is influenced by ideological orientation. What they found out, was that conservatives and Republicans taught at lower quality schools, compared with liberals and Democrats. This suggested, they argued, "that conservative complaints of the presence and effects
of liberal homogeneity in academia deserve to be taken seriously".

A 2014 study by Iyengar and Westwood [3] underscored how powerful political bias can be. In an experiment, Democrats and Republicans were asked to choose a scholarship winner from among fictitious finalists, with the experiment tweaked so that applicants sometimes included the president of the Democratic or Republican club. Four-fifths of Democrats and Republicans alike chose a student of their own party to win a scholarship, and discrimination against people of the other party was much greater than discrimination based on race.

For a 2016 study [4], Shields and Dunn surveyed 153 conservative professors. “As two conservative professors,” they wrote in The Washington Post, “we agree that right-wing faculty members and ideas are not always treated fairly on college campuses. But we also know that right-wing hand-wringing about higher education is overblown.” Nevertheless, about one-third of the professors professors admit to using "coping strategies that gays and lesbians have used in the military and other inhospitable work environments", ie they "closeted" themselves by passing as liberals. Some also said they were badly mistreated on account of their politics.

In a 2017 speech before the Stanford Board of Trustees [5], former Provost John Etchemendy argued that he "watched a growing intolerance", "a political one-sidedness, that is the antithesis of what universities should stand for". "It manifests itself", he argued "in the intellectual monocultures that have taken over certain disciplines; in the demands to disinvite speakers and outlaw groups whose views we find offensive; in constant calls for the university itself to take political stands".

In 2009, world–renowned political scientist Norman Finkelstein was denied tenure at DePaul University for his criticisms of Israel's human rights violations against the Palestinian people [6]. In 2014, co-discoverer or DNA James Watson was forced to sell his Nobel prize after losing most of his income for stating that people of African descent are less intelligent than white people [7]. In 2017, graduate student Lindsay Shepherd was hauled before a three-person panel at Wilfrid Laurier University, which interrogated her for more than 40 minutes for showing a first-year communications class a video snippet from TV Ontario of Jordan Peterson debating another professor on the use of gender pronouns [8]. In 2018, University of Pennsylvania Law School professor Amy Wax was removed from teaching mandatory first-year courses for saying in an interview that she didn't think she'd ever seen a black student graduate in the top quarter of the class [9].

These are some of many examples where academics / scholars have been reprimanded for making statements deemed too "politically incorrect" by their employers. While such cases are obviously but annectodal evidence at best, they do suggest Etchemendy may have had a point when he said he watched a growing intolerance "that is the antithesis of what universities should stand for". They do suggest it may indeed be safer for conservative professors to pass as liberals. They do suggest that French may have had a point when he argued there was systematic suppression and censorship of conservatives. And they do suggest that Rothman, Nevitte and Lichter may have been right to conclude that that conservative complaints of the presence and effects of liberal homogeneity in academia deserve to be taken seriously.

---

[1] Pierce, Fort (2005) ["Conservatives Censored on College Campuses?"](https://abcnews.go.com/WNT/story?id=461497&page=1)

[2] Rothman, Stanley; Lichter, S. Robert; Nevitte, Neil (2005). ["Politics and Professional Advancement Among College Faculty"](http://www.conservativecriminology.com/uploads/5/6/1/7/56173731/rothman_et_al.pdf)

[3]: Iyengar, Shanto; Westwood, Sean (2014). ["Fear and Loathing across Party Lines: New Evidence on Group Polarization"](https://pcl.stanford.edu/research/2015/iyengar-ajps-group-polarization.pdf)

[4] Jon A. Shields; Joshua M. Dunn Sr. (2016). ["Passing on the Right: Conservative Professors in the Progressive University"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199863059)

[5]: Etchemendy, John (2017) ["The threat from within"](https://news.stanford.edu/2017/02/21/the-threat-from-within/)

[6]: Klein, David (2009) ["Why Is Norman Finkelstein Not Allowed to Teach?"](http://www.worksanddays.net/2008-9/File14.Klein_011309_FINAL.pdf)

[7] Perry, Keith (2014) ["James Watson selling Nobel prize 'because no-one wants to admit I exist"](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/11261872/James-Watson-selling-Nobel-prize-because-no-one-wants-to-admit-I-exist.html)

[8]: Walkom, Thomas (2017) ["The problematic case of the Wilfrid Laurier TA who dared to air a debate on grammar"](https://www.thestar.com/opinion/star-columnists/2017/11/24/the-problematic-case-of-the-wilfrid-laurier-ta-who-dared-to-air-a-debate-on-grammar.html)

[9]: Diaz, Andrea (2018) ["Law prof ousted from first-year classes after saying black students never graduated top of their class"](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/16/us/penn-removes-professor-for-racial-remarks-trnd/index.html)

Comment: Your post doesn't really include much of anything about _why_, only a rehashing of conservative complaints about being a minority.  The only possibly relevant citation of empirical research is the Iyengar study, but that finds equal bias in both directions.

Comment: @jakebeal : What about the study by Rothman, Stanley & Lichter? And what about the study by Shields & Dunn? Why do you consider these studies irrelevant? And what about the overal tendency towards suppression and censorship of conservative thought as described by French, Etchemendy and numerous other sources? How is this not relevant in light of the aforementioned studies?

Comment: They all explore potential differences and consequences, but offer no evidence regarding causation.

Comment: @jakebeal : When one-third of the professors surveyed in Shields and Dunn admit to using "coping strategies that gays and lesbians have used in the military and other inhospitable work environments" to avoid discriminating and some even state having been "mistreated on account of their politics", this clearly confirms that systematic suppression and censorship is a causal factor worth considering, as is the fact that that conservatives and Republicans taught at lower quality schools, as demonstrated by Rothman, Nevitte and Lichter.

Comment: @jakebeal (continued) : Anyway, do note that the modetor's note below the question "states that we "may use comments ONLY to suggest improvements" and that "moderators will remove debates, arguments or opinions without notice". So unless you have any suggestions for improvements, please suggest them. Otherwise, I'm afraid we have to end this interaction due to being in bread of that request.

Comment: My apologies for being too indirect: I would suggest that in order to improve the post, you remove all of the material that is simply claiming that conservatives are mistreated in academia. Your other sources allege systematic suppression without any empirical evidence of why one might expect to always find a group of powerful suppression-minded liberals even in generally conservative regions and institutions.

Comment: @jakebeal : I don't see how LESS sources to back of the fact that conservatives are systematicly suppressed and censorshiped would be an improvement of my answer. If anything, my answer would benefit from MORE sources to support this. —  No one is arguing that there is ALWAYS a group of powerful suppression-minded liberals, even in generally conservative regions and institutions. That's a pretty silly strawmen, really, and you should know better than to suggest something like that.

Comment: @jakebeal : (continued) The fact is simply that most conservatives believes that colleges should expose students to all types of viewpoints even if they are offensive or biased against certain groups, whereas Liberals generally prefer the suppression and censorship of viewpoints they deem offensive or biased. As a demonstration, see eg. [this survey](https://spec.hamilton.edu/free-speech-survey-support-for-discourse-strong-but-self-censorship-endures-ca7c152c902f) by Hamilton university's studenty paper.

Comment: @jakebeal : (continued) As a consequence, we see that colleges with a predominantly Liberal establishment (which appear to be the majority) are actively involved in the suppression and censorship of viewpoints deemed offensive or biased by this Liberal establishment. And this prevents many conservatives from rising in the academic food chain, unless they hide their conservative views, at least until ther obtain tenure.

Comment: @jakebeal : (continued) Either way, as I said, I don't see how your suggestions are going to improve my answer and I honestly can't imagine you convincing me otherwise. So, let's please respect the moderation's wishes not to engage in debates, arguments or the expression of opinions any further.

Comment: I agree with the first comment by @jakebeal at the start. The question that was asked was: "Is there any serious empirical research into why professionals in academia are more likely to vote democratic than the average of the population? If so, what are the main explanations? " What you offer is a descriptive account, claiming that conservative opinions/voices are being silenced or discouraged, but in the large mass of text it's hard to see an answer to those questions. Some of your comments might serve better as an answer, since they make analytical claims, not just descriptive accounts

Comment: @JohnSlegers I see that you have been reproached for not providing enough empirical support to your claims of discrimination of conservatives in academia. Please feel free to borrow evidence and references from [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/110059/what-research-explains-political-attitudes-of-academics/196539#196539) , if you wish.